# How to make normalize to work on all types of arrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

This won't work `normalize([1 2])` it works only for `normalize([1, 2])`.

How to make it accept all types of lists, arrays and vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

normalize works on vectors, and [1 2] is a 2-dimensional matrix.

```
julia> [1, 2] isa Vector
true

julia> [1 2] isa Vector
false
```

You can make a flattened version of a matrix with [:], as in:

```
julia> [1 2][:] isa Vector
true
```

So you can call normalize([1 2][:]) without a problem:

```
julia> normalize([1, 2]) == normalize([1 2][:])
true
```

Note that using vec also works and avoids one extra copy:

```
julia> normalize([1, 2]) == normalize(vec([1 2]))
true
```

To avoid *any* copies, you can use normalize! instead of normalize to change the vector in-place (note that normalize! prefers floating point, not integer values).

Look up reshape() if you need to get the original [1 2] shape back.

Comment: Doesn't that create a copy? Better use `vec`.

Comment: yes it does, as does normalize. I'll add that option.